# Вид условия при 404

Tags: java, вконтакте, бот

Есть некий бот для вк с командой "вики". 
При существующей в вики статье, бот даёт на неё ссылку. При несуществующей всё еще даёт ссылку, но с FileNotFoundException. Какого вида необходимо сделать условие, чтобы предотвратить exception и вывести сообщение вида "статья не найдена"?

```
@Override
public String execute(IDialog dialog, String[] args, Bot bot) {
    String text = ObjectJoiner.join(" ", args);
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + text).openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.connect();
        connection.getInputStream().close();
        return "Лови!<br>" + URLDecoder.decode(connection.getURL().toString(), "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

Вид ексепшена при несуществующей статье следующий:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at ru.hilgert.cmds.commands.WikiCommand.execute(WikiCommand.java:45)
    at ru.hilgert.cmds.HBotCmds.dispathCommand(HBotCmds.java:254)
    at ru.hilgert.cmds.HBotCmds.handleCmd(HBotCmds.java:208)
    at ru.hilgert.cmds.HBotCmds.onCmd(HBotCmds.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ru.hilgert.hbot.events.EventHandlerMethod.invoke(EventHandlerMethod.java:23)
    at ru.hilgert.hbot.plugin.PluginManager.fireEvent0(PluginManager.java:118)
    at ru.hilgert.hbot.plugin.PluginManager.fireEvent(PluginManager.java:110)
    at ru.hilgert.hbot.Bot$MessageConsumer$1$1.call(Bot.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Решение проблемы следует оформлять как ответ на вопрос, а не в качестве редакции исходного сообщения

Answer (score 0):

пофикшено изменением

```
   } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    return e.getLocalizedMessage();

}
```

на

```
   } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    return "Статья не найдена";


}
```